# Can I use a variable as an argument in get_the_ID()?

Tags: php, wordpress

Note: I am still a beginner in both PHP and WordPress so apologies if I'm way off.

I am trying to echo the custom field value from the latest post from the 'video' post format, but for some reason, `$video_url` is outputting an empty string. I'm thinking it has to do with this line below:

`$video_url = htmlspecialchars(get_post_meta(get_the_ID($latest_video_id), 'dt_video', true));`

I'm not sure if I'm allowed to use a variable as an argument in `get_the_ID()`.

Here is the full code:

```
<?php   
    $args = array( 
        'numberposts' => '1', 
        'tax_query' => array(
            array(
                'taxonomy' => 'post_format',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => 'post-format-video'
            )
        ),
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => 'dt_video',
                'value' => '',
                'compare' => '!='
            )
        )
    );
    $latest_video = wp_get_recent_posts($args); // Get latest video in 'video' post format
    $latest_video_id = $latest_video['0']['ID']; // Get latest video ID
    $video_url = htmlspecialchars(get_post_meta(get_the_ID($latest_video_id), 'dt_video', true));
    echo '<iframe width="180" height="101" src="'.$video_url.'?rel=0" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>';
?>
```

Comment: Why should a function disallow passing a variable? It's at most the other way around: you cannot pass a value (e.g. `"string", 123`) as a reference.

Comment: @ComFreek Yeah, that's what I was thinking, but I'm not sure why $video_url is coming up empty.

Comment: Then just break it down into it's components and check each separately, does `get_the_ID($latest_video_id)` return what you expect, does `get_post_meta(get_the_ID($latest_video_id), 'dt_video', true)` return what you expect, ....

Comment: @Desi: This is exactly why: `htmlspecialchars(get_post_meta(get_the_ID($latest_video_id)` — Break them into multiple statements and debug them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi get_the_ID() returns the id of the current post when you are inside the loop. does not accept any parameter.

You allready have the id of the video post in the var $latest_video_id, so you can simply do

```
$video_url = htmlspecialchars(get_post_meta($latest_video_id, 'dt_video', true));
```

good luck.

Comment: Thank you, this made the url output! But now I get an error in the console saying `Refused to display 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l4X2hQC32NA&feature=g-all-u&context=G258729eFAAAAAAAAHAA?rel=0&output=embed' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'.` I tried adding `&output=embed` to the end of the video url but I still get the same error. This is causing the video to not display, although the output is correct. Any ideas?

Comment: it throw the same error to me, i try using the embed url of video and insert ok http://www.youtube.com/embed/l4X2hQC32NA maybe this help

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't change the URL since it's the value of the custom field that the theme creator set up. Is there any way to change the url to the embed version dynamically? Edit: Actually, never mind. This isn't in the scope of the question and I will do my research. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, you can use regular expressions to extract the code part of the url

Answer (score 0):

You are always able to use an argument as long as it returns something. You should be receiving some type of error if it's not working.

Example:

```
function getId()
{
  return 1;
}
function showId($id)
{
  return $id;
}
echo showId(getId());
```

Result: 1